# Linker error "undefined reference to" with Eigen template functions

Tags: c++, oop, templates, eigen

I'm attempting to write a class that solves a system of nonlinear equations (a root finder). For this, I've written a class that encapsulates all the internal functions needed, as well as the system to solve: a function that takes an Eigen vector and returns an Eigen. The public `newt` member function takes an Eigen vector (the initial guess), runs the algorithm with that initial guess, and returns the Eigen vector `r` such that `func(r) = {0, 0, ..., 0}`. I've written the functions as prescribed [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html): writing template functions that take instantiations of `MatrixBase`.

The way I've handled taking an arbitrary function to solve was to implement a base class and then have the user extend it, defining `func`, the function to solve. The class I have is

```
class Newt {
private:
    template<typename TR, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
    tuple<TR,bool> lnsrch(const MatrixBase<T1> &xold, const double fold, const MatrixBase<T2> &g, MatrixBase<T3> &p, const double stepmax);

    template <typename TR, typename T1, typename T2>
    TR fdjac(const MatrixBase<T1> &x, const MatrixBase<T2> &fvec);

public:
    template <typename TR, typename T1>
    TR func(const MatrixBase<T1>&);

    template <typename TR, typename T1>
    tuple<TR,bool> newt(const MatrixBase<T1> &xx);
};
```

The user then inherits from Newt and overrides the `func` method to the desired function to solve:

```
struct NewtD : public Newt
{
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    T1 func(const MatrixBase<T2> &z) {
        // Content
    }   
};
```

Then he instantiates it and calls the newt member function. However, when I compile this with the following test case:

```
struct Newt3 : public Newt
{
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    T1 func(const MatrixBase<T2> &x) {
        return (Vectord<3>() << 
            z(0),
            z(1)*z(2),
            pow(z(2)-1,2)
        ).finished();
    }   
};

int main() {
    Newt3 solver3;
    bool check;
    tie(X,check) = solver3.newt<Vectord<3>>(X);
}
```

I get the following linker error, when compiling with g++ 6.2.0

```
undefined reference to `std::tuple<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, bool> Newt::newt<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> >(Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> > const&)'
```

It seems it can't find `newt`? I have no idea why this is, the signature in the error seems to match my code, everything seems okay. Any idea how to solve this?

PS: Oh yeah, I forgot: `Vectord<N>` is a shortcut template type simply defined as

```
template<size_t N>
using Vectord = Matrix<double, N, 1, 0>;
```

PPS: The implementation is in a separate file. I didn't include it because it's quite big, but bottom-line is every function is defined there, including `Newt::newt`

```
template <typename TR, typename T1>
tuple<TR,bool> Newt::newt(const MatrixBase<T1> &xx) {
    // Body
}
```

Comment: `Newt::newt` doesn't appear to be implemented. It's certainly absent from the code you've shown here. Apparently, it's absent from the code you've shown to the compiler, too.

Comment: No, it's implemented in the `.cpp`. I didn't include it because it is quite long. I will add the skeleton to the question for clarity.

Comment: Templates must be implemented in the header. The definition has to be visible to the compiler at the point where the template is used and its parameters become known.

Comment: How so? You mean if I have a class template I cannot split the declaration (`.h`) and the implementation (`.cpp`) into two files? I didn't know of that.

Comment: Today you learned. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea that was the case. I would never have thought of that. However this is very impractical. Not only do I have to forgo separating between a declaration file and a definition file, I will end up having to put *everything* in the same file, since `Newt3::func` will end up, in my use case, depending on other functions such as a gaussian integrator. This would mean I would have to put everything: declaration, definition, derived class, `func` declaration, and everything `func` might depend on, on the same file. That is highly impractical.

Comment: Welcome to C++. If a compiler cannot read the definition of a template, it cannot generate the code, resulting in undefined references. I don't have the exact percentages, but I wouldn't be surprised if more than half of the C++ library code consists of templates defined in the header files. Everything in `<algorithm>` is a header file. Everything in various container header files is a template, etc...

Comment: It makes sense. The answer @Igor linked cleared things up for me. How do you deal with dependency problems, though? Say my `func` depends on something else. I have to bring everything into the same file?

Comment: @andrepd: Do keep in mind that headers can `#include` each other; so you don't need everything to literally be in the same file, just in the same translation unit. And if your templates depend on any *non*-template functions, then those non-template functions can still be *defined* in .cpp files, as long as they're *declared* in .h files (and not defined as static/inline/whatnot).